# How to redirect to PageReference from constructor

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, community, redirect

I need to prevent user from accessing standard community pages like /login and /sitelogin, because I have custom branded pages. In Salesforce SiteLogin.component there is no option for action (method that executes on page load), so maybe there is another way to do redirect?
Javascript would be bad option because it is not safe.

Comment: You can use an `action` tag for example on the _page_ `SiteLogin`, where the actual component is used on. Or implement the logic in the custom controller of the `SiteLogin` _page_.

Comment: @SergeyUtko There is no SiteLogin page available. I think Salesforce just allows to customize layout by giving access to component only.

Comment: It is not true. Once enabled (communities/site) you should get access either to [`CommunitiesLogin`](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=communities_custom_login_page.htm&language=en_US) or  [`SiteLogin`](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_login_and_registration_settings.htm&language=en) that are default login pages created automatically by system. Try to search for it within dev console.

Comment: @SergeyUtko thanks, I solved problem with /sitelogin, but user can still type '/login' in url and go to default login page. I can create url redirect, but it does not work if I pass any url parameters to that page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of handling your issue. One is simply by [branding the standard community login page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/networks_customize_login_branding.htm). Another is by [modifying the Apex community and/or sites login Controller](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=communities_custom_login_page.htm&language=en_US) so that it redirects to your custom login page.